# Frustration Installing Laravel on Ubuntu

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu

Now I remember why I never got into PHP. It's such a pain to set up. I spent a couple hours today trying to complete a coding challenge which required me to install Composer, Vagrant, VirtualBox and Laravel.

Somewhere along the line I think my permissions or something changed, because whenever I try to install Laravel...

`composer global require "laravel/installer"`

I get...

```
Changed current directory to /home/dilraj/.composer

  [ErrorException]                                                             
  file_put_contents(./composer.json): failed to open stream: Permission denied                                                                            


require [--dev] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [--no-update] [--no-scripts] [--update-no-dev] [--update-with-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [--sort-packages] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--] [<packages>]...
```

I am not sure why I am getting this, perhaps it is because I have already done it, but regardless, when I try to create an executable command I am not seeing any results.

I edited the `.bashrc` file, as such...

`export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin`

`source ~/.bashrc`

I am not going to lie, I don't what this is even doing. I just want to make it so I can type 'laravel' and then start doing stuff, kinda like in npm.

Here are other things I tried but succeeded without any luck :(

`export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin"`

`export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin"`

`alias laravel='~/.config/composer/vendor/bin/laravel'`

Comment: why do you need install laravel "globally" ?

Comment: Good, PHP doesn't like you either. Anyways your question is heavily geared towards a Laravel install in specific. According to your error messages, PHP is correctly abiding by the rules of your filesystem so I'm not sure why you have such angst against PHP.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus yeah you are right. I just remember that whenver I got into PHP and it's frameworks, it was always a mission and a half.

Answer (score 1):

You don't you address the issue noted in the error, primarly `Permission denied`. Running `chmod 755 .composer` should be enough to give you permission to edit the file.

If that doesn't work, add `sudo` in front of it to update it using root account.

Answer (score 0):

seems like you have install composer as root. 
You can try to install laravel without Laravel Installer by run :

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel projectfolder
```

It its not working, try using sudo command :

```
sudo composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel projectfolder
```